# Bootstrap Modal Footer Height for Dynamic Content

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

For my forms that are within a modal, I've opted to use the bootstrap modal footers to display any errors related to the form. This is causing some frustrations when the errors inevitably make the footer take up more height than the footer has available. I'm fine with it needing more height, but I want it to add the height to the top and have the modal body's height reduced so the modal as a whole stays the same height. If it adds it to the bottom it ends up pushing content off the screen. The modal body accounts for content that's too "tall" and adds vertical scroll bars which is why I'm willing to give up modal-body height to accomodate the modal footer height.

I've added a link to an image of what I'm referring to. The modal footer expands to the content as expected, but adds that height to the bottom so the rest of the modal footer becomes inaccessible when its pushed off screen. I want to steal height from the body so the footer's added height gets added to the top and the modal's total height stays the same size.

[image]

I'm sure there's a simple fix I haven't found yet but I thought I'd ask while I continue to look in case someone else has already found a solution they want to share. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Normally bootstrap modal uses fixed positionong. In case when content is to large scrollbars appears inside the modal.

If you want to have long modals with no scrollbars you must first change modal positioning to `absolute`. But if your site content is long you must add some `top` property value. It's because now modal is vertically positioned to whole site, not to current browser view, so % top will not work anymore.

```
.modal {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
}
```

Now to scroll you just use browser scrollbar.

Next to get rid of modal scrollbars you add `max-height: inherit` to `modal-body` class. Now modal will get larger depending on a content without scrollbars.

```
.modal .modal-body {
    max-height: inherit;
}
```

Yes this has some disadvantages. The biggest one is that if you launch modal on the bottom of the page you might not even see it because it will popup on the top of the page.
For this issue you can add js scroll top script after modal is fired.

```
$('#myModal').on('show', function () {
    $("body").animate({
        scrollTop:0
    });
});
```

Hope that helps!